# Display 2 Layouts dynamically in 1 Activity

Tags: android, button, dynamic, view, android-linearlayout

i have a card game app. What i want:When a certain card comes(via random gen.) there should be 2 different buttons displayed, and when another certain card comes, then there should be 3 different buttons.So i know there has to be a 2 different layout files , which then get displayed in the main layout, depending on the card. I read some tutorials about dynamically adding Views, but it does not work like i want. Thanks for all tipps/code/links

Comment: Can you put some code that shows what you do and what is not like you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with visibility... GONE means the object is there but has no consistency - it's like a **ghost**. INVISIBLE means that it's there hidden - it's like a **chameleon**. VISIBLE... no comment!
Visibility is easily set:

```
txtScore.setText("" + score);
txtScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You'll need to import View, if it's not already in your imports

Comment: Works like a charm, I combined both your answers. I remove (view.gone) and add (view.visible) 2 LinearLayouts inside the main layout, thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with any of  below mentioned ways :

1. Have all your layouts in a single layout file and do hide and show layouts based on your need.
2. You can dynamically add and remove layout.
3. The preferred and most elegant way :  use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)